# Разные ip адреса на двух доменах в одном сервере, почему?

Tags: linux, debian, ip

На сервере linux debian стоит plesk 12. Через панель plesk было создано два сайта с разными доменами и директориями:

/site1.com/httpdocs/

/site1.com/site.com/

Хотел запустить cron, затем обнаружил что ip адреса при запросе wget у двух доменов отличаются. Проверил через команду ping через ssh и действительно адреса отличаются.
У первого домена (site1.com) все работает и показывает внутренний ip адрес сервера, у второго (site.com) показывает внешний ip адрес и в следствие показывает ошибку 404 not found при запросе `wget http://site.com/`

Comment: преврашение имен доменов в ip делает DNS. это никак не касается настроек вашего сервера. Где находятся файлы зон для ваших доменов. у вас на сервере и у вас поднят dns-сервер на который указывают NS записи от регистратора доменных имен. Или все настройки зоны у вашего регистратора - тогда надо менять настройки через интерфейс регистратора

Comment: Все настройки днс на моем сервере, все делал через plesk. Настройки dns у двух доменов идентичны.

Comment: А у регистратора домена NS записи точно указывают на ваш сервак ? И где вы расположили вторичный DNS. для одного домена и первичный и вторичный DNS не должны находится на одной машине.

Comment: Как я понял первичный через plesk, вторичный через robot.your-server.de у хостера - hetzner. Как можно это проверить?

Comment: запускаете nslookup. указываете `set Q=NS`, пишите имя домена. видите NS. даете `set Q=A` по очереди переключаете сервера с которых спрашивать `server ip` и опять вводите имя домена и смотрите, что отвечают конкретные DNS сервера. Так же, если дело происходит на той же машине, где стоит dns-сервер - смотрите /etc/resolv.conf там заданы адреса DNS серверов которыми пользуется ваша собственная машина для определения любых имен.

Comment: Проверил через панель plesk, на двух доменах стоит статус: This server acts as a primary nameserver for the DNS zone

Comment: @Mike спасибо за совет, попробую, чуть позже отпишусь

Comment: @Mike ip адреса через команду set `Q=A` и `set Q=NS` идентичны на двух доменах, единственная разница это адреса при `ping` этих доменов через ssh

Comment: Это что то интересное. А оба DNS сервера одинаково отвечают ? Бывает что секондари не забирает вовремя изменения с примари. А еще имя может быть прописано в /etc/hosts он для ping и прочих важнее dns ...

Comment: возможно проблема заключается в настройке ip адресов в панели управления plesk? там есть три ip адреса: 171.хх.ххх.ххх; ip вида ipv6 и 88.xx.xxx.xx при подключение к домену через ping в ssh в первом домене где все работает - отображает ip 171.хх.ххх.ххх и ip вида ipv6. При запросе на второй домен показывает внешний ip адрес 88.xx.xxx.xx

Comment: да вы правы @Mike. Открыл файл /etc/hosts - там написано `# IPv6
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
172.xx.x.100 site.com site 
2a01:4f8:c17:xxxx::2 site.com site`

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен благодаря совету @Mike. 
Для того чтобы убедиться что `ping` через `ssh` дает верный `ip`, нужно зайти в папку `/etc/hosts` и прописать дополнительно нужный `ip` адрес к домену и пользователю.

Comment: Или может просто убрать упоминания из hosts, тогда все по DNS будет работать

Comment: Не знаю что именно делается, но каждому юзеру сайта /etc/hosts не отредактируешь ведь